# Problema al minificar para producción uglify

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, gulp

Estoy desarrollando una web app con angularjs, mi version de node es 6.9.4, el proyecto funciona perfecto en entorno de desarrollo, pero al minificar los archivos, para ponerlo en producción me sale este error

```
    events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
    at expect_token (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2110:9)
    at expect (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2113:36)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2686:13)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2136:24)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2616:35)
    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2792:19)
    at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2827:24)
    at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2832:20)
    at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2856:20)
    at expression (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2875:20)
    at expr_list (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2641:24)
    at subscripts (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Proyecto sigecuta front git\sigecutac\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2775:30)
```

le agregue la librería gulp util, para que me marque la linea del error y me sale esto:

[image: error]

me marca error en el index.html, es la raiz del proyecto,  donde se inyectan los scripts...

¿porque es este error?, me sale ese error para poder ponerlo en producción, gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

este es mi gulpfile

```
/*
* Limpiar Directorio Producción
*/
gulp.task('limpiar', function() {
    gulp.src('./dist/', { read: false }) // much faster
    .pipe(rimraf());
});

/*
* Optimización del código
*/
gulp.task('plantilla', function () {
    gulp.src('./source/app/**/**/**/**/**/**/**/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache({
            root: 'app/',
            module: 'templates',
            standalone: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./source/app/'));
});

gulp.task('comprimir',function() {
   gulp.src('./source/index.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify({mangle: false })))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));     
});

gulp.task('copyHtml', function() {
    gulp.src('./source/lib/fontawesome/fonts/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));

     gulp.src('./source/index.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});

//Copia de Imagenes a Carpeta Producción
gulp.task('copiarImg',function() {
        gulp.src([
        './source/images/**/**.*'
    ])
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/images/'));
})
```

Comment: Hola, te puedo colaborar, tambien trabajo con angular y herramientas de npm, gulp, grunt...  podemos mirar tu gulpfile.js

Comment: editaré para mostrar

Comment: el error me sale al tratar de minificar estuve mirando y no me genera el app.min.js

Comment: el css si lo genera minificado?

Comment: el css si lo genera, deberia  generar una carpeta js donde pone vendor.min.js y app.min.js, el vendor lo genera, pero el app.min.js no, lo mas curioso es que esa misma plantilla la use para otro proyecto y ese funciona normal.

Comment: mmm interesante, sigamos mirando entonces que podemos descartar.

Comment: Hasta ahora ya corregi errores de consola, ya descarte que fuera alguna libreria, revise que las rutas de mi index existieran los archivos realmente, lo que descubrí es que en el index donde se inyectan las dependencias el vendor corresponde a las librerías de bower, y el app.min,js a mis archivos en la carpeta app, y es allí donde falla al parecer, pero no entiendo la razón.

Comment: Cuéntame amigo, como le termino de ir? si logro conseguir una solución.

Comment: aun no sigue el error

Comment: no se donde buscar ni que pueda ser

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64435/discussion-between-pablo-and-bastianburst).

Comment: lo siento olvide comentar pero ya lo solucioné luego de revisar mucho, logre hacer un console al error y me daba error Uglify SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (}) expected punc :, este error es porque uglify no soporta ES2015, y en un controlador tenia esa notación, la cambie a notación ES5 y solucionado.

Comment: Que bien @BastianBurst me alegro amigo para servirte en lo posible que se pueda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo siento olvide comentar pero ya lo solucioné, luego de revisar mucho, logre hacer un console al error y me mostraba `Uglify SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (}) expected punc :`, lo indicaba en el index porque el error lo detectaba luego de minificar, es decir en el app.min.js que genera, este error es porque uglify no soporta ES2015, y en un controlador tenia esa notación, tenia algo así.

```
 Eventos.remove({
                 idEventos
            })
```

la cambie a notación ES5 y solucionado,

queda asi en notacion ES5

```
 Eventos.remove({
                 idEventos: idEventos
            })
```

En desarrollo funciona igual ya que no es un error de sintaxis en si, pero al minificar es otro tema ya que uglify no lo soportaba, de todas formas gracias a los que dedicaron tiempo para responder.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que hay un error al useref tratar de parsear el index.html, el index tiene que tener este aspecto:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- build:css css/combined.css -->
    <link href="css/one.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/two.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- build:js scripts/combined.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/one.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/two.js"></script> 
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Necesitaría ver el index.html para poder decirte algo más.